# Unexpected token 'Create' in expression or statement

Tags: powershell, token

I'm trying to create a new user in PowerShell under my new OU, but it keeps giving me an error.

This is what I'm entering into PowerShell:

```
$newUser=$newOU create("User","cn=myTestUser1")
```

And this is the error:

```
Unexpected token 'Create' in expression or statement.
+ $newUser=$newOU Create <<<< ("User","cn=myTestUser1")
```

[image]

And yes, I already created a new OU.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Maybe you mean `$newOU.Create` instead of `$newOU Create`?

Comment: I don't recommend guesswork in trying to get to a solution.